# Using systemd to automatically start, restart, stop, and daemonize a script

Tags: systemd

I have a simple script which launches a process (optionally as a daemon) and saves its pid to a file.  I can invoke it manually.

I'd like systemd to:

- Run it on boot
- Restart if it fails
- Run it as a particular user, group, and umask
- Implement stop via `kill [pid from the pidfile]`

Also, can systemd daemonize something automatically, so I don't need the daemon code in my script? How do I do that?

Comment: Yes, systemd can do all that, and there are dozens of tutorials out on the Internet.

Comment: That's almost as helpful as "don't use Passenger.".  I of course read about systemd beforehand, and found the references, but nothing that clearly showed a beginner how to do the above.  If you can point to a source, great.

Comment: Start with 15-30 minutes on the excellent [Red Hat documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/system_administrators_guide/sect-managing_services_with_systemd-unit_files)? This explains everything you need to know, all at once. A search for "how to write a systemd unit" brings up many other tutorials as well, some of which might be less information-dense.

Comment: @SRobertJames It might be easier if you show what you have tried so far and the problems you are having.